# How can I view organic SEO traffic keywords in the new Google Analytics 4?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-hosting

I created a Google Analytics account with Firebase hosting, but it seems that the type of GA account is limited compared to the "plain website" account that used to be created.

Question: How can I view the keywords that users clicked for incoming SERP traffic?

Below are two pictures - the newer Firebase-created GA UI (with no keywords), and the older GA UI that allows viewing keywords.

[image: GA 4]

[image: Older GA]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a programming question. Reporting questions are better asked e.g. at webmasters.stackexchange.com. Also your keywords are in the search console, but currently this cannot be linked to GA4.